# Remove <item> tag for array complex type in apache axis wsdl

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wsdl, axis

I am trying to integrate our java spring application to a client system. The client system needs to call one of our SOAP webservices for providing data. They already have a system in place and we will be replacing it. Client is not ready to make any changes on their side and has asked us to have the Webservice in the same format as they have it now. When we try to generate WSDL using Apache Axis 1, its giving and extra `<item>` tag and is repeating that tag instead of actual array parameter

They have provided the existing WSDL as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s0="http://danateq.com/soap/link/eventgateway" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://eventIndication" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://eventIndication" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://danateq.com/soap/link/eventgateway">
      <s:import />
      <s:element name="EventIndication" type="s0:Input" />
      <s:complexType name="Input">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="UserID" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="UserIDType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="OrigPlatformID" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="OrigPlatformNode" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="EventID" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Parameter" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <s:element name="UserID" type="s:string" />
      <s:element name="UserIDType" type="s:string" />
      <s:element name="OrigPlatformID" type="s:string" />
      <s:element name="OrigPlatformNode" type="s:string" />
      <s:element name="EventID" type="s:string" />
      <s:element name="Parameter" type="tParameter" />
      <s:complexType name="tParameter">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ParameterType" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ParameterValue" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="EventIndicationSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="EventIndication" element="s0:EventIndication" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="EventIndicationSoapOut" />
  <wsdl:portType name="PointsService2Soap">
    <wsdl:operation name="EventIndication">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:EventIndicationSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:EventIndicationSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="PointsService2Soap" type="tns:PointsService2Soap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="EventIndication">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://EventIndication" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="PointsService2Soap12" type="tns:PointsService2Soap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="EventIndication">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://EventIndication" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="PointsService2">
    <wsdl:port name="PointsService2Soap" binding="tns:PointsService2Soap">
      <soap:address location="http://loyaltydev/Loyaltyws/PointsService2.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="PointsService2Soap12" binding="tns:PointsService2Soap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://loyaltydev/Loyaltyws/PointsService2.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The soap request for the above wsdl is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:even="http://danateq.com/soap/link/eventgateway">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <even:EventIndication>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <UserID>?</UserID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <UserIDType>?</UserIDType>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <OrigPlatformID>?</OrigPlatformID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <OrigPlatformNode>?</OrigPlatformNode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <EventID>?</EventID>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <Parameter>
            <ParameterType>?</ParameterType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ParameterValue>?</ParameterValue>
         </Parameter>
      </even:EventIndication>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Using this wsdl we have generated the objects using wsdl2java ( Apache axis 1.1). Now issue starts when we try to generate the webservice using these classes. 
The wsdl generated using apache axis is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://webservices.api.inspirenetz.com" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://webservices.api.inspirenetz.com" xmlns:intf="http://webservices.api.inspirenetz.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://webservices.api.inspirenetz.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <complexType name="TParameter">
    <sequence>
     <element name="parameterType" type="xsd:int"/>
     <element name="parameterValue" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="ArrayOfTParameter">
    <sequence>
     <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="impl:TParameter"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="Input">
    <sequence>
     <element name="eventID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="origPlatformID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="origPlatformNode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="parameter" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOfTParameter"/>
     <element name="userID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="userIDType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <element name="input" type="impl:Input"/>
   <element name="EventIndicationReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>

   <wsdl:message name="EventIndicationResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:EventIndicationReturn" name="EventIndicationReturn">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="EventIndicationRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:input" name="input">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="FastdataWebService">

      <wsdl:operation name="EventIndication" parameterOrder="input">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:EventIndicationRequest" name="EventIndicationRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:EventIndicationResponse" name="EventIndicationResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="FastdataWebServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:FastdataWebService">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="EventIndication">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="EventIndicationRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="EventIndicationResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="FastdataWebServiceService">

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:FastdataWebServiceSoapBinding" name="FastdataWebService">

         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/services/FastdataWebService"/>

      </wsdl:port>

   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

The SOAP request for the above wsdl is generated as

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.api.inspirenetz.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:input>
         <web:eventID>?</web:eventID>
         <web:origPlatformID>?</web:origPlatformID>
         <web:origPlatformNode>?</web:origPlatformNode>
         <web:parameter>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <web:item>
               <web:parameterType>?</web:parameterType>
               <web:parameterValue>?</web:parameterValue>
            </web:item>
         </web:parameter>
         <web:userID>?</web:userID>
         <web:userIDType>?</web:userIDType>
      </web:input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the original request has the repeating array ( Parameter object) represented as

```
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
<Parameter>
    <ParameterType>?</ParameterType>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ParameterValue>?</ParameterValue>
</Parameter>
```

But the one generated using Apache Axis has got an additional `<item>` tag inside  that is getting repeated

```
<web:parameter>
    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <web:item>
       <web:parameterType>?</web:parameterType>
       <web:parameterValue>?</web:parameterValue>
    </web:item>
</web:parameter>
```

Here instead of repeating the Parameter tag, its repeating a `<item>` tag inside the parameter tag.

I am also providing the class Input and Parameter for the reference

**Input.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Input", namespace = "http://danateq.com/soap/link/eventgateway", propOrder = {
    "userID",
    "userIDType",
    "origPlatformID",
    "origPlatformNode",
    "eventID",
    "parameter"
})
public class Input {

    @XmlElement(name = "UserID")
    protected String userID;
    @XmlElement(name = "UserIDType")
    protected String userIDType;
    @XmlElement(name = "OrigPlatformID")
    protected String origPlatformID;
    @XmlElement(name = "OrigPlatformNode")
    protected String origPlatformNode;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventID")
    protected String eventID;
    @XmlElement(name = "Parameter")
    protected TParameter[] parameter;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the userID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the userID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setUserID(String value) {
        this.userID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the userIDType property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getUserIDType() {
        return userIDType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the userIDType property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setUserIDType(String value) {
        this.userIDType = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the origPlatformID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getOrigPlatformID() {
        return origPlatformID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the origPlatformID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrigPlatformID(String value) {
        this.origPlatformID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the origPlatformNode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getOrigPlatformNode() {
        return origPlatformNode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the origPlatformNode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrigPlatformNode(String value) {
        this.origPlatformNode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the eventID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getEventID() {
        return eventID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the eventID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setEventID(String value) {
        this.eventID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the parameter property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the parameter property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getParameter().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link TParameter }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public TParameter[] getParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

**TParameter.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "tParameter", propOrder = {
    "parameterType",
    "parameterValue"
})
public class TParameter {

    @XmlElement(name = "ParameterType")
    protected int parameterType;
    @XmlElement(name = "ParameterValue")
    protected String parameterValue;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the parameterType property.
     * 
     */
    public int getParameterType() {
        return parameterType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the parameterType property.
     * 
     */
    public void setParameterType(int value) {
        this.parameterType = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the parameterValue property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getParameterValue() {
        return parameterValue;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the parameterValue property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setParameterValue(String value) {
        this.parameterValue = value;
    }

}
```

I have tried different array structure, `List<TParameter>` to see if this will get rid of the `<item>` tag. Nothing seems to work.

It would be highly appreciated if someone could direct me in getting the definition right so that the exact same request format will be generated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse and auto generating the Java Code for the WSDL using new->web service->web service tool, then before you generate the java code go to eclipse menu window->preferences->axis emitter-> tick the checkbox named "Prefers building beans to straight arrays for wrapped XML array types"